# How to set a UIImageView from a view controller called in with instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I'm using storyboards and I need to use subview to import a xib. The xib is simply to display an image. It has a UIImageView and a UIBarButtonItem. How do I set the image once I've imported it as a subview?

I've tried setting methods in the h+m files for the subview xib but maybe I'm doing it wrong. Here's my code

```
-(void)showPreviewImageScreen:(UIImage *)image 
{

    UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController* vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"libraryImagePreview"];

    [vc setPreviewImage:image];

    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:vc.view];

}
```

The error i get says "No visible @interface for UIViewController declares the selector 'setPreviewImage'"

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a method called setPreviewImage (as far as I know).  You set the image with setImage: but that has to be called on your UIImageView that's in your xib, not on your view controller vc.

Answer (score 0):

@rdelmar Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.. This is the solution I came up with..
I tagged the UIimageView with 1, then looped through the subviews to find this tag and target it this way.

```
-(void)showPreviewImageScreen:(UIImage *)image 
{

    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"libraryImagePreview"];


    for (UIView *subview in vc.view.subviews)
    {
        if(subview.tag==1)
        {
            UIImageView *IV = subview;
            [IV setImage:image];
        }
    }

   [self.navigationController.view addSubview:vc.view];

}
```